# Use JWT Auth with Google's new Load Balancer (Envoy)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, envoyproxy, gcp-load-balancer

is it possible to handle authentication (using a JWT) with Google's Load balancer?. I know it uses Envoy proxy under the hood to handle advance traffic management. But is it just that?, I know Envoy has native implementations to validate JWT (using HTTP filters), does this GCP LB version can use that?.

If thats not the case, do you know any GCP service that can manage this type of logic+LB? (besides Google's Api Gateway)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use JWT Auth to GCP Load balancer. However you might want to explore  [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/signed-headers-howto#before_you_begin) for this concern.

Let me also share with you the [overview](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview) of IAP for further understanding.

You can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto#enable-iap) on how to enable IAP on external load balancer under backend service. Also note that there are possibilities of changes depending on what resource you are using.

Comment: I see, thanks for your response!. Is it possible to configure IAP with a custom authentication/authorization method?. I want to validate a custom JWT for authentication and a custom business logic for authorization

Comment: You can check this [feature](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_a_user_account) from IAP if this one can fit with your requirements.